# Creating a self-extracting zip archive on a linux box

Tags: linux, windows-installer, installation, zip, winzip

Due to a number of constraints that I won't get into, I have to create a self-extracting ZIP archive on a linux box. The resulting archive should be executable on Windows only. Is this at all possible? If so, what tools would do the job?

Background: when the user downloads a setup package from my linux box, I need that setup package to be pre-populated with a certain key. I only know that key at runtime; my idea was to write a simple .xml file with that key, then zip up the .msi installer with that xml file into a self-extracting archive, and send that file to the browser. If you have alternative ideas on how to make it happen, I'd love to hear those, too

Comment: You'll need to make clear on which specific platform the archive should be executable.

Comment: Added a clarification - Windows only.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your answer can be found at the following page: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=847329  Please note that I do not take credit for anything other than using Google and finding something that sounds logically like it would work.  I do not guarantee that this information will work, or that you will be able to find the mentioned materials online anymore.  I'm just a fan of Google.  I hope this helps.

> The problem A few days back I had to
>   create a Win32 compatible
>   self-extracting ZIP file for a friend.
>   Sounds easy, right. The problem was
>   that I didn't have a Windows machine
>   nearby and I didn't want to install
>   any archiving programs under Wine.
>
> NOTE: A freeware ZIP program such as
>   IZArc under Wine can be used to create
>   a Win32 self-extracting ZIP file too.
>   That will not be covered by this
>   howto, sorry.
>
> The "research" Googling around I found
>   this forum post dated August 2003.
>   Reading it I found out that
>   self-extracting ZIP files are nothing
>   more but a suitable unzip binary
>   followed by a normal ZIP file. I used
>   the unzipsfx.exe included in Info-ZIP
>   UnZip 5.52.
>
> The link on that post worked a few
>   days ago so I got my hands on the
>   unzipsfx.exe that I was looking for.
>   Today, 2nd July 2008 I found the link
>   dead. After some googling I didn't
>   find a working link anywhere. I read
>   the licence a few times and understood
>   that I can redistribute the original
>   unzipsfx.exe with a license included.
>
> Please note that the
>   unzipsfx-552_win32.tar.gz (80 kB) is
>   not an official Info-ZIP package and
>   it includes copyrighted software that
>   I take no credit for. More info in the
>   Info-ZIP license that is also included
>   in the tarball. The source code for
>   the binaries included can be found
>   here.
>
> The solution
>
> Step one, getting the unzipsfx.exe and
>   zip package:
>   * open the Terminal (in Ubuntu press alt+f2 and type gnome-terminal)
>   * type in the following commands Code:
>
> wget
>   http://kolmoskone.homelinux.org/~kaja/kamaa/unzipsfx-552_win32.tar.gz
>   tar zxf unzipsfx-552_win32.tar.gz sudo
>   apt-get install zip
>
> Step two, creating a ZIP file in
>   Ubuntu:
>   * open the file manager (nautilus) and select the files you want to have
>   zipped
>   * right click and select Create an archive (or similar). Select a
>   location for the ZIP file, using your
>   home directory is the easiest. Select
>   type .zip. See man zip for information
>   on how to create a ZIP file in command
>   line.
>
> Step three, making the ZIP file
>   self-extracting
>   * type in the following commands Code:
>
> cat unzipsfx-552_win32/unzipsfx.exe
>   MYZIPFILE.zip > mysfxfile.exe zip -A
>   mysfxfile.exe
>
> mysfxfile.exe can now be opened in any
>   Win32 compatible system (including for
>   example Windows XP/2000/Vista and even
>   Wine in Linux) or ANY ZIP COMPATIBLE
>   archive program such as file-roller in
>   Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make this work with unzipsfx. There's a newer version of it available - just came out in April 2009 - version 6.0. Version 5.52 didn't support the critical functionality that I needed - launching a particular setup file after the extraction is completed.

So I downloaded the source files for 6.0. I then modified them to exclude the "prompt to launch stuff" check that is there by default. I recompiled using Visual Studio 2008, tried the steps described in the tutorial above, and it all works like a charm now.

Comment: If you've found the answer, could you please mark it correct? Also, linking from the answer to the page with the software would be helpful.